# How to Render Images in sitecore jss Component?

Tags: jss

I am new to sitecore JSS as I followed the Official sitecore documents and created an app and then Scaffold one component to this app and also rendered Few single line and rich text Fields but i am not getting any idea how to render the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample apps contain a Styleguide page that has example components of how to render different field types and the options thereof, including images. For example, in React [this is the sample component](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/react/src/components/Styleguide-FieldUsage-Image/index.js).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react';

/**
 * Demonstrates usage of an Image content field within JSS.
 * Image field data is uploaded into the Sitecore Media Library.
 */
const StyleguideFieldUsageImage = (props) => (
  <Image media={props.fields.sample1} />
);

export default StyleguideFieldUsageImage;
```

Comment: Thanks for help Kam,
now can you please tell me how to add Image field in en.yml , where full path of my yml file is like \myapp\data\routes\en.yml???

Comment: Load up the styleguide page; it tells you where to find the component and data file for each field type sample.